# How to unit test a specific class in PyCharm? (using 2017 version)

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, configuration, pycharm

I used to have a class button in 'edit configuration' which I don't have anymore in the latest version. Any idea?

edit: In the previous version clicking on "Class" radio button (which is not available anymore) would make a text field appear where I would type the class name. Not sure where I can type this now.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using your same setting you had before for your *class* settings but using the *Python* radio button?

Comment: In the previous version clicking on "Class" radio button (which is not available anymore) would make a text field appear where I would type the class name. Not sure where I can type this now.